# Dining Philosophers implementation using mutex locks

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, synchronization

I am trying to implement a deadlock free implementation of the DP problem, but my implementation sometimes gives bizarre results. Such as this one:

> 5
>
> Thread 4 is hungry
>
> Thread 4 is eating
>
> Thread 5 is hungry
>
> Thread 3 is hungry
>
> Thread 4 is thinking
>
> Thread 3 is eating
>
> Thread 5 is eating
>
> Thread 5 is thinking
>
> Thread 1 is hungry
>
> Thread 2 is hungry
>
> Thread 1 is eating
>
> Thread 3 is thinking
>
> Thread 2 is thinking
>
> Thread 1 is thinking

In this the Thread(Philosopher) 2 becomes hungry and starts thinking without eating ,i.e, the function call of pickup returns for thread 2, which should not be the case. Maybe i don't understand how pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal work. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
enum state
{ T, H, E };
enum state *st;
pthread_mutex_t mutex, mut, mu;
pthread_cond_t *var;
int n;
void pickup (int philo_num);
void test (int i);
void putdown (int i);
void *philo (int i);
int
main ()
{

  scanf ("%d", &n);
  pthread_t threads[n];
  var = (pthread_cond_t *) malloc (n * sizeof (pthread_cond_t));

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    pthread_cond_init (var + i, NULL);

  pthread_mutex_init (&mutex, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_init (&mut, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_init (&mu, NULL);

  st = (enum state *) malloc (n * sizeof (enum state));

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    *(st + i) = T;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, philo, i);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      pthread_join (threads[i], NULL);
    }
  return 0;

}

void
pickup (int philo_num)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
  *(st + philo_num) = H;
  test (philo_num);

  if (*(st + philo_num) != E)
    pthread_cond_wait (&mutex, (var + philo_num));

  pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
}

void
test (int i)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock (&mut);
  if ((*(st + ((i + n - 1) % n))) != E && (*(st + i) == H)
      && (*(st + ((i + 1) % n))) != E)
    {
      *(st + i) = E;
      printf ("Thread %d is eating\n", i + 1);
      pthread_cond_signal ((var + i));
    }
  pthread_mutex_unlock (&mut);

}

void
putdown (int i)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock (&mu);
  *(st + i) = T;
  printf ("Thread %d is thinking\n", i + 1);
  test ((i + 4) % 5);
  test ((i + 1) % 5);
  pthread_mutex_unlock (&mu);
}




void *
philo (int i)
{
  int j = 0;
  while (j == 0)
    j = rand () % 4;
//      printf("Thread %d is thinking\n",i+1);
  sleep (j);
  printf ("Thread %d is hungary\n", i + 1);
  pickup (i);
  sleep (j);
  putdown (i);
//      printf("Thread %d is thinking\n",i+1);

}
```

Comment: When 2 was hungry and wanted to eat, both 1 and 3 were currently eating. So 2 waited. But 2 never tried to eat again. So he never ate. When the pthread_cond_wait returns then the philosopher (who is still hungry) should try to eat again. Right now the philosopher does not try to eat again.

Comment: regarding: `void *philo (int i)`  This is NOT a valid signature for a pthread function.  A valid signature would be: `void *philo( void *parm)`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (`malloc` `calloc` `realloc` ) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: there are several examples of performing the 'dining philosophers` problem on stackoverflow.com,  Suggest you perform a bit of googling

Comment: Note: this kind of problem is much easier to solve using 'semaphores' rather than 'mutexs'